# How to underline header paragraph section in Latex

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I've read a lot of questions that are quite similar to mine, but I couldn't make any of them work properly. What I'd like is to have below the "subsubsection" the paragraph (not numbered and not included in the indeces).

I would like the header of the paragraph to be underlined, bold and the rest of the text beginning after a new line. I've tried **ulem** and **sectsty**, but non of them worked as desired. Currently I'm using the following code:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me (although underlining tiles is not at all advisable: it was used in the times of typewriters, because one could not do any better):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{titlesec}

 \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\uline}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{test}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and the help. It works perfectly... You are totally write regarding the usage of underlining.. It's just that I have "sections,subsections and subsubsections"... and I'd need one extra subcategory, which would distinguish from the rest of the text in a nice way, while not being a subcategory of the ones on top (especially numbered... 1.2.3.1.2 :P )..

Comment: You might write paragraph titles in italic (non-bold), maybe `\large` to differentiate from the other sectioning levels. And/or add a bullet (or a square bullet, possibly soberly coloured) before the titles. It's left up to your imagination…